# Type punning, Unions and std::stack

Tags: c++, struct, stack, unions

Let's say I want to push into a standard library stack different types of data.
To simplify I'll take just two types:

- int
- foo (class)

For this I'll need the following data structures:

```
//generic class
class foo {
  private:
    float x_;
  public:
    foo(float x) : x_(x){};
};
 
//simple enum
enum element_type {
  footype,
  number
};

struct stack_element {
  element_type type_;
  union {
    foo* obj;
    int num;
  } data;
};
```

Then I'll need to create a constructor inside my struct in order to achieve the type punning:

```
//actually this should be if/else statement in this case but on the code problem I have more types
stack_element(element_type type, foo* obj){
  switch(type){
    case footype: 
      this->type_ = type;
      this->data.obj = obj;
    break;
    case number:
      this->type_ = type;
      // Here comes the type punning
      this->data.num = *(int*)&obj;
    break;
    default: throw("Unknown type");
    break;
  }
}
```

and then the main.cc would look like this:

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  foo myobj (3.24);
  int a = 2;

  std::stack < stack_element > mystack;

  mystack.push (stack_element (element_type::footype, &myobj));
  mystack.push (stack_element (element_type::number, (foo *) a));

  do {
    if(mystack.top().type_ == number){
      std::cout << (int)mystack.top().data.num << std::endl;
      mystack.pop();
    }
    else{
      mystack.top().data.obj->print_foo();
      mystack.pop();
    }
  }while(!mystack.empty());
    
    return 0;
}
```

This will compile with a warning which obviously makes sense:

> main.cpp:73:62: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
> 73 |   mystack.push (stack_element (element_type::number, (foo *) a));

Now that the bases are set, I have a couple of questions:

- Are there any other workarounds that could be more efficient in order to do the same goal.
- I've read that this way is not really accepted and that now we have std::variant since c++17 but as it says:

> A variant is not permitted to hold references, arrays, or the type void.
> (Unless you use a reference_wrapper.)

Should I use std::variant instead of this union/struct?

- I guess it's not a really safe code right?

Comment: `stack_element(element_type type, foo* obj)` Don't cause yourself suffering like this. If you have to go the custom variant route, use overloaded functions, `stack_element(foo* obj)`and `stack_element(int val)`, instead. The one called with an `int` stores `val` and sets `type_ = number`. The `foo*` version stores `obj` and sets the type to `footype`. Simple, stupid, no punning, and easy to test.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I use std::variant instead of this union/struct?

Yes, you should use `std::variant` instead of `struct stack_element`.

> I guess it's not a really safe code right?

No, your code isn't really safe.